# XSLT 1.0 - conditional node assignment

Tags: xslt, xpath

using pure XSLT 1.0, how can I conditionally assign the node. I am trying something like this but it's not working.

```
<xsl:variable name="topcall" select="//topcall"/>
<xsl:variable name="focusedcall" select="//focusedcall" />

<xsl:variable name="firstcall" select="$topcall | $focusedcall"/>
```

For variable `firstcall`, I am doing the conditional node selection. if there is a `topcall` then assign it to `firstcall`, othersie assign `firstcall` to the `focusedcall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 Solution** This short (30 lines), simple and parameterized transformation works with any number of node types/names:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pRatedCalls">
   <call type="topcall"/>
   <call type="focusedcall"/>
   <call type="normalcall"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vRatedCalls" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pRatedCalls']/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vpresentCallNames">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vRatedCalls">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "name($vDoc//*[name()=current()/@type][1])"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "//*[name()
       =
        substring-before(normalize-space($vpresentCallNames),' ')]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to this XML document** (do note the document order doesn't coincide with the specified priorities in the `pRatedCalls` parameter):

```
<t>
 <normalcall/>
 <focusedcall/>
 <topcall/>
</t>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<topcall/>
```

**when the same transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <normalcall/>
 <focusedcall/>
</t>
```

**again the wanted and correct result is produced**:

```
<focusedcall/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The names of the nodes that are to be searched for (as many as needed and in order of priority) are specified by the global (typically externally specified) parameter named `$pRatedCalls`.
2. Within the body of the variable `$vpresentCallNames` we generate a space-separated list of names of elements that are both specified as a value of the `type` attribute of a `call` element`in the`$pRatedCalls` parameter and also are names of elements in the XML document.
3. Finally, we determine the first such name in this space-separated list and select all elements in the document, that have this name.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pRatedCalls" select=
  "'topcall', 'focusedcall', 'normalcall'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "//*
     [name()=$pRatedCalls
                [. = current()//*/name()]
                                        [1]
     ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1, good solutions. This takes advantage of the fact that the OP's alternatives are strictly based on element names. I was creating a more general solution for any nodeset variables regardless of the content... but you've pointed out that it's not necessary for this question.

Comment: @Dimitre - Thanks for this generalized solution. For a new, can you please the first statement <xsl:param name="pRatedCalls">
   <call type="topcall"/>
   <call type="focusedcall"/>
   <call type="normalcall"/>
 </xsl:param>

Comment: @rpg: I have added a detailed explanation of the XSLT 1.0 solution. Please, ask any additional questions you might have.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstcall" select="$topcall[$topcall] |
                                       $focusedcall[not($topcall)]" />
```

In other words, select `$topcall` if `$topcall` nodeset is non-empty; `$focusedcall` if `$topcall` nodeset is empty.

**Re-Update** regarding "it can be 5-6 nodes":

Given that there may be 5-6 alternatives, i.e. 3-4 more besides $topcall and $focusedcall...

The easiest solution is to use `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstcall">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$topcall">    <xsl:copy-of select="$topcall" /></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$focusedcall"><xsl:copy-of select="$focusedcall" /></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$thiscall">   <xsl:copy-of select="$thiscall" /></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>               <xsl:copy-of select="$thatcall" /></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

However, in XSLT 1.0, this will convert the output of the chosen result to a result tree fragment (RTF: basically, a frozen XML subtree). After that, you won't be able to use any significant XPath expressions on `$firstcall` to select things from it. If you *need* to do XPath selections on `$firstcall` later, e.g. `select="$firstcall[1]"`, you then have a few options...

1. Put those selections into the `<xsl:when>` or `<xsl:otherwise>` so that they happen before the data gets converted to an RTF. Or,
2. Consider the `node-set()` extension, which converts an RTF to a nodeset, so you can do normal XPath selections from it. This extension is available in most XSLT processors but not all. Or,
3. Consider using XSLT 2.0, where RTFs are not an issue at all. In fact, in XPath 2.0 you can put normal if/then/else conditionals inside the XPath expression if you want to.
4. Implement it in XPath 1.0, using nested predicates like

:

```
select="$topcall[$topcall] |
        ($focusedcall[$focusedcall] | $thiscall[not($focusedcall)])[not($topcall)]"
```

and keep on nesting as deep as necessary. In other words, here I took the XPath expression for 2 alternatives above, and replaced $focusedcall with

```
($focusedcall[$focusedcall] | $thiscall[not($focusedcall)])
```

The next iteration, you would replace $thiscall with

```
($thiscall[$thiscall] | $thatcall[not($thiscall)])
```

etc.

Of course this becomes hard to read, and error-prone, so I would not choose this option unless the others aren't feasible.

Comment: can you please explain little bit as I am very new to XSLT.

Comment: The bar `|` is a union operator (not logical `or`). You were previously taking the union of the two nodesets. LarsH's solution takes the union of two mutually exclusive sets, which always results in one or the other.

Comment: @rgp: yes, this is for XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Larsh - Thanks for this great explanation. But I am not still clear with 5-6 node examples. By 5-6 nodes, I mean similar to topcall, focusedcall, I might also have thiscall, thatcall etc etc in such case, how would I find the firstcall.

Comment: @rpg - I updated my answer in regard to 3 or more alternatives.

Comment: @LarsH: Could be quite simpler :)

Answer (score 3):

Does `<xsl:variable name="firstcall" select="($topcall | $focusedcall)[1]"/>` do what you want? That is usually the way to take the first node in document order of different types of nodes.

Comment: Martin - I tried the same, but seems it's not working. we have defined nodes for both topcall and focusedcall. With this conditional node assignment, I want the firstcall to assign the topcall if it exists else focusedcall. FYI, In input xml, focusedcall appear first before the topcall.

Comment: @rpg: "It's not working" needs to be specified better. What result are you getting, and how does it differ from your expectation?

Comment: one more point, this OR is not just for two it can be 5-6 nodes. Also, there are chances that the position of topcall and focusedcall may change, so it seems that it will be little bit difficult for me to rely on anything which relates to document order.

Comment: @rpg - This is all information that you need to include in your question. If there are more important details, please edit to include your actual question.

Comment: This is an XSLT 2.0 idiom, if you replace "|" by ",". It doesn't work in XSLT 1.0, in the general case, because "|" returns nodes in document order. It can be used if you know that when both nodes exist, $topcall will always precede $focusedcall